# extract individual variable(yes/no) from combination of multiple variable(yes/no)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, data-cleaning

suppose we have columns of

```
+------+-----+-----+
|  a+b | b+c | c+d |
+------+-----+-----+
| No   | yes | No  |
| Yes  | No  | No  |
| No   | No  | Yes |
+------+-----+-----+
```

how to obtain it's individual from the combination info as

```
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
    | no  | yes | yes | no  |
    | yes | yes | no  | no  |
    | no  | no  | yes | yes |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I have humongous data and I can't keep using "or"  condition for each and everything.

Comment: Do you have an array or do you have the string you send?
Please edit your question with the exact data you have (a list if it is a list, a dict if it is a dict, a dataframe if it is a dataframe)

Comment: it's a dataframe .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 dataframes with `rename` columns, join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then get maximal value per duplicated columns:

```
d = {'No':0, 'yes':1, 'Yes':1, 'no':0}
df1 = df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.split('+').str[0])))
df2 = df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.split('+').str[1])))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1).replace(d).max(axis=1, level=0).replace({0:'no', 1:'yes'})
print (df)
     a    b    c    d
0   no  yes  yes   no
1  yes  yes   no   no
2   no   no  yes  yes
```